# Get children post mime type using parent post_ID wp_post

Tags: php, posts

Consider parent post_id is 11 for the same post. If I add media, the information about media is passed to the post_id 12 by taking parent_id 11 in wp_post.

So, if I want to get media information using `get_post_id()` as a parameter, it returns the mime type of post 11 which will be null, but for that id I need to fetch its children post data, lets say 12.

Comment: You've used the tag 'plugins'. Is this code in a plugin? Your question is a bit confusing

Comment: there you go i removed plugins, if you could please let me know what clarification you need from me, i can do it in a better way